Alternator intermittent not charging
2014 ram 1500 3.6L v6
Alternator went out a month ago and had to be replaced by dealership, OEM Mopar part. Drove almost 10000km no problems. Then yesterday after 4hrs driving got battery voltage low message. Turned off truck, waited, went some more, after about 10-15 min battery voltage low msg again. Got towed back to town. This morning, truck seems running fine.
Getting 14.3v at battery + and - posts while running.
Getting 16.3v at alternator pole to alternator case. This seems high.
I checked resistance of alternator pole to battery + terminal, no resistance.
There was a stored message when I used scan tool, voltage high. Missed what code it was (p056 something)
Any idea why it would be putting out 16.3v at alternator? But battery only getting 14.3? All electronics seem to work fine.
Buying new alternator tomorrow just in case it's bad voltage regulator. Otherwise idk why it would have low battery voltage. Could it automatically shut off to prevent over charging? Could it stop charging only when really hot? Belt seems tight and was replaced when alternator was (less than 1mth ago).
Went to Napa auto parts and their tester said everything is good. Battery good, alternator good, battery load tested good as well. Battery is 4mths old.

It was P0563 voltage high.

And the alternator and battery have both been replaced. Tested voltage from alternator output to battery positive and there is no difference.

Don't replace that alternator yet!
Two things --
FIRST: If possible, measure voltage at the alternator and at the battery with an old-school analog voltmeter. You know, the kind with the needle that points to a graduated scale. Alternators produce a rectified 3-phase AC voltage. Yes, it's sorta kinda DC, but it contains a lot of ripple, and some digital voltmeters give wacky readings when set to DCV to measure a voltage source with a lot of ripple. The ripple may be less problematic when measured physically close to the battery, which smooths things out. The old school meter will measure the average DC voltage wherever you connect it.
SECOND: An alternator on a 2009 Ram 2500 drove me crazy for a few weeks with an allegedly low voltage message that was never low when I measured it. I did a running voltage and current test under heavy load using a carbon pile tester. Good. I continuity tested and voltage tested all the wires between the ECU and the alternator. Fine. And then while I was watching just by chance, the voltage dropped to the low 12's for a few seconds, I got a low voltage warning, and then the voltage returned to normal.
It turned out that a carbon brush that contacts a slip ring that feeds the field coil in the alternator was worn down to a nub and it was giving intermittent contact. It would have been easily repairable, but the replacement brush set was backordered for a couple of weeks while a replacement alternator was available same-day. I reluctantly changed the alternator but kept the old one to repair when the brush set became available. Now it's a spare.
Any chance your new alternator is a rebuild and it didn't get a new set of brushes at the rebuild facility? You can open the alternator and check the condition of the brushes.
Have you followed a test procedure that verifies all the wires between the ECU and the alternator?
Either issue could be giving you intermittent alternator output.

And by the way, you're measuring volts at the battery POSTS. Try measuring on the battery cable CLAMPS and see if it's different. That would indicate poor contact between posts and clamps.

Thanks. Getting same readings when measuring at posts vs clamps.
